# Segmentation Fault in constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

In my TeamMatcher.C, I have the following bit of code:

```
void TeamMatcher::makeTeamSet(){                                                                                                          
  //Segmentation fault here:                                                                                                               
    Team tempTeam(rosterExcellent[0]);
  //...more code in this method below this point, but it has all been commented out.
```

rosterExcellent is a vector

Here is the constructor for Team(Student member1):

```
Team::Team (Student member1)
{
  // members is a vector<Student> instance variable in Team
  // commonHrsAvailable is a vector<int> in Team


  // members.push_back(member1);                                                                                                                                  
  //commonHrsAvailable = member1.hrsAvailable;                                                                                                                   
  //numberOfCommonHrsAvailable = commonHrsAvailable.size();                                                                                                       
}
```

Notice all the lines are commented out and I still get the segmentation fault.
This is the last bit of code to be executed.

Now, I messed around changing members to vector, changing this constructor's parameter to a Student*, and the rosterExcellent to vector (as well as changing the . notation to -> where appropriate). I got it to the point where it would run the first line of the constructor (members.push_back(member1)), but it seg faulted on the next line (even after I changed to -> notation).

Comment: Is it possible that `rosterExcellent` is a null pointer or an empty vector?

Comment: What's in rosterExcellent? Is it instantiated and does an element exist at position 0?

Comment: Show us the `Student`'s copy constructor and destructor.

Comment: OMGOIH@#ORIFHEOFHEIEFWH:!!!
What a noob move! Thank you! *runs away in shame*
Can close this as that was a pretty noob mistake!

Comment: Actually, I'd recommend against closing it.  It will probably be helpful to others, but only if you can provide a little more detail as to the problem you discovered... was rosterExcellent indeed null or empty?

Comment: It was indeed that rosterExcellent was the problem. I had previously divided the roster into proficiency levels. Then I decided I could sort the entire roster by level and keep them all in on roster. So rosterExcellent[0] didn't exist. Doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rosterExcellent[0]` is either `NULL` or not initialized properly.